# Why is true not pushed correctly in my javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

this is my first question here.I have been doing FCC challenges.I came across challenge "Seek and Destroy".
Below is my complicated code :P

```
function destroyer(arr) {
    // Remove all the values
    var newarr = [];
    var final = [];
    for (var l = 0; l < arr[0].length; l++) {
        newarr.push(true);
    }
    console.log(newarr);
    for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < arr[0].length; j++) {
            if (arr[i] == arr[0][j]) {
                newarr[j] = false;
            }
        }
    }
    for (var k = 0; k < arr[0].length; k++) {
        if (arr[0][k] & newarr[k]) {
            final.push(arr[0][k]);
        }
    }
    return final;
}
destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);
```

The code is supposed to remove all elements from the initial array that are of the same value as these arguments.
Please correct me as I might be bad at coding.Thanks!

Comment: So your code is working? Then you should rather ask for possible improvements, or bad practices over on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Yept.Thanks guys.Got it corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the ES6 rest parameters you may still use your destroyer function arguments the way you have originally intended. Accordingly the following  might also serve your purposes

```
destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3)
function destroyer(arr, ...killThemAll){
  return arr.filter(e => !killThemAll.find(k => k == e))
} // <- [1, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you are passing the values is wrong. Use the following way because you expect to receive a single value in the function.

```
destroyer([[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3]);
```

```js
function destroyer(arr) {
    // Remove all the values
    var newarr = [];
    var final = [];
    for (var l = 0; l < arr[0].length; l++) {
        newarr.push(true);
    }
    console.log(newarr);
    for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < arr[0].length; j++) {
            if (arr[i] == arr[0][j]) {
                newarr[j] = false;
            }
        }
    }
    for (var k = 0; k < arr[0].length; k++) {
        if (arr[0][k] & newarr[k]) {
            final.push(arr[0][k]);
        }
    }
    return final;
}
alert(destroyer([[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3]));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use arrays filter function:

```js
function destroyer(arr,arrdel) {
        return arr.filter(function(k){
            return (arrdel.indexOf(k) == -1)
        })
    }
document.getElementById("snippet").innerHTML = destroyer([1,2,3,1,2,3],[1,3])
```

```html
<div id="snippet"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Arguments Object.

```
function destroyer(arr){
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    return arr.filter(function(value){
        return args.indexOf(value) == -1;
    })
}
destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);
```